# Joining two tables at random

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables, on with main data, and another shorter table with additional data.

I would like to join the rows from the shorter table to some of the rows of the main table, at random. For example:

**main table:**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | banana |
| 3 | cherry |
| 4 | date |
| 5 | elderberry |
| 6 | fig |

**secondary table:**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | accordion |
| 2 | banjo |

**Desired Result:**

| main | secondary |
| --- | --- |
| … ? | accordion |
| … ? | banjo |

I can think of one way to do it, using a lot of pre-processing with CTEs:

```sql
WITH
    cte1 AS (SELECT data FROM main ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2),
    cte2 AS (SELECT row_number() OVER() AS row, data FROM cte1),
    cte3 AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS row, data FROM secondary)
SELECT *
FROM cte2 JOIN cte3 ON cte2.row=cte3.row;
```

It works, but is there a more straightforward way of joining two tables at random?

I have attached a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21af08976112c7ac7c18329fa3699b8c&hide=2

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is basically just a re-usable template for a subquery.
So this can be golfcoded to using 2 subqueries.

```
SELECT m.rn, m.data main_data, s.data secondary_data
FROM (SELECT data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random()) rn FROM main) m
JOIN (SELECT data, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random()) rn FROM secondary) s USING (rn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could rewrite it to this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) as id,
             data
      FROM main
      ORDER BY RANDOM()) m1
JOIN secondary s on s.id = m1.id
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ebe476aeb0221ef2e7e27d23458b1d21&hide=2)

Update: LIMIT is not needed after looking at @LukStorm's version

I assumed that you know which table is shorter so there is only one column with generated `id's`